# Library to handle QRCode generation serverside and store within database?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, qr-code

What I want to accomplish:

When a user hits "Generate QRCode" javascript will take the local machine's datetime and create an md5 hash based on the MMDDYYHHMMSS format. I want to take that hash and have the server generate a QRCode based on that hash and store it within the server's media folder. However all the libraries for QRCode take input and generate the QRCode clientside with no image resources, so I have no way to store it.

Does anyone have any answers as to how I should approach such an implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a server side PHP library which will generate a JPG / PNG / GIF or your QR code.

https://github.com/edent/QR-Generator-PHP/

So, take the hash, pass it to your webserver. Generate the QR code, and then save it.